# Як перекласти українською "User Experience"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Індустрія інформаційних технологій використовує термін "user experience" та "gaming experience", який означає суб'єктивні відчуття користувача програмного забезпечення. Навіть є сайт [User Experience.StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), присвячений розробці **зручного у використанні** програмного забезпечення.

Більшість сайтів, на яких публікуються I.T.-новини, [перекладають цей термін так](http://ua.gecid.com/news/drajver_nvidia_geforce_378_66_whql_game_ready/):

> *Новий драйвер забезпечує оптимальний **ігровий досвід***

Мені такий термін здається не зовсім вдалим з тієї причини, що в англійській слово *experience* має два сенси:

1. короткотермінових відчуттів прямо зараз
2. обсяг знань, умінь і навичок, які утворилися внаслідок довготермінового занурення в якусь предметну царину — власне, *«досвід»*.

Чи є більш адекватний термін, який передає значення (1), а не (2)?

Comment: Якщо у значенні №1, то я б переклав "ігрові враження". Приклади використання: [1](http://www.sony.ua/electronics/playstation), [2](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/uk-ua/products/gaming/xbox-360-wireless-controller-for-windows/jr9-00010)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Старе питання, але вставлю свої 5 центів, може хтось ще підніме його з пилу

Цифрова/ІТ-сфера вже давно є невід'ємною частиною бізнесу і маркетингу, тому на Заході є ряд термінів, які поєднують бізнес і цифрову сферу, коли перед словом *experience* стоїть приміром *user, customer, developer, digital* або інше слово.

### Взаємодія

Загалом у таких випадках можна вживати слово *"взаємодія"* або в значенні окремої одиничної взаємодії когось із чимось, або в значенні регулярної взаємодії, після якої залишається певний досвід, враження і відчуття. При цьому *З ЧИМ* саме або *З КИМ* саме взаємодіють по-англійськи зазвичай не вказують і воно зрозуміло само собою.

Тобто:

- ***user experience*** = *взаємодія користувача* (з продуктом, сервісом або інтерфейсом); інколи в значенні самого *інтерфейсу*, з яким взаємодіє користувач (приклад буде нижче); інколи в значенні *"оптимізація взаємодії користувача"*, тобто діяльність або комплекс заходів, спрямованих на поліпшення взаємодії користувача (*user experience is a conglomeration of tasks focused on the optimization of a product for effective and enjoyable use*)
- ***game experience*** = *взаємодія гри* (з гравцем) або (гравця) з грою
- ***customer experience*** = *взаємодія клієнта* (з компанією, продуктом або сервісом)
- ***developer experience*** = *взаємодія розробника* (з програмним рішенням або програмним продуктом)
- ***digital experience*** = *цифрова взаємодія* (взаємодія клієнта з цифровими точками компанії або конкретний цифровий канал взаємодії); можна також сказати *"цифровий канал взаємодії"*, це підтверджує той факт, що серед digital experiences є email, websites, social medias, chatbots і т.д. (хоча є винятки, що будуть згадані нижче, коли слово *"канал"* все таки недоречне)
- ***digital customer experience*** = *цифрова взаємодія клієнта* (it is the sum of the user's digital interactions with a company throughout their buyer journey)
- ***support experience*** = *взаємодія з підтримкою* (зі службою техпідтримки компанії)

По логіці може здаватись, що краще вживати множину, тобто *"взаємодія користувачІВ"* або *"взаємодія розробникІВ"*. Але цього краще не робити, бо тоді вираз виглядатиме як взаємодія таких осіб МІЖ СОБОЮ або їхня співпраця між собою.

На слово ***"взаємодія"*** (англ. *interaction*) як головний відповідник (хоча не єдиний) вказують наступні цитати з мережі:

> **User experience** (UX) is the **interaction** and experience users have with
> a company's products and services.
>
> **Customer experience** is every **interaction** a buyer has with your brand,
> online and offline.
>
> A **digital experience**, also known as DX, is any digital **interaction**
> that a customer has with any of your company's digital touchpoints.

Крім того, в деяких випадках при перекладі на українську можна вживати такі слова і вислови як *"процес", "процес використання", "процес взаємодії" або "використання/користування"*.

На слово *"процес"* як на одне зі значень слова experience зокрема вказують деякі з пояснень [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experience)

- (the **process** of getting) knowledge or skill from doing, seeing, or feeling things

а також [dictionary.reference.com](https://dictionary.reference.com/browse/experience)

- the **process** or fact of personally observing, encountering, or undergoing something

### Варіанти перекладу:

**user experience**

- *better user experience of the app* - краща/більш приємна взаємодія користувача з додатком; хоча можна також сказати "краще/більш приємне використання додатку користувачем" або "кращий/більш приємний процес використання додатку користувачем"
- *the end user experience is decoupled from the content management system... the end user experience (aka the frontend) communicates with WordPress* - в даному випадку згідно aka (і це також зрозуміло з контексту самої [сторінки](https://netlify.com/blog/2019/05/16/wayfx-deploys-lightning-fast-headless-wordpress-to-netlify), з якої взято даний уривок) під experience мають на увазі так званий "фронтенд" (інтерфейс), який відділений від бекенду; "досвід" або "відчуття" в цьому випадку не можуть бути відділені від певної частини (layer) програмного забезпечення

**game experience**

- *for a fullscreen game only experience* - для користування грою або для взаємодії з грою лише в повноекранному режимі

**digital experience**

- *build world-class websites and digital experiences*
- *manage all your omni-channel digital experiences* - це приклад коли недоречно буде сказати *"цифрові канали"* бо тоді вийде *"масляне масло"*
- *production-ready experiences* - (цифрові) продукти або взаємодії, готові для продакшену
- *rich development experiences such as intelligent code completion* - тут до experiences відносять інтелігентне завершення коду, тобто певне програмне рішення
- *create truly interactive experiences* - створити дійсно інтерактивні взаємодії

**інші випадки**

- *bring tools to CMS experience* - "взаємодія з CMS" або "процес використання CMS"
- *tool experience developers love* - використання інструменту, яке полюбляють розробники; в даному випадку розробники не можуть полюбляти відчуття
- *capabilities with a clean and modern content editing experience* - тут підійде "сучасний процес редагування контенту"
- *enable a single sign-on experience for your users* - активувати процес SSO або процес використання SSO для ваших користувачів; тобто активувати опцію в панелі керування, а не "відчуття" або "досвід"
- *help us improve your experience with our support team* - допоможіть нам поліпшити вашу взаємодію з нашою службою підтримки

---

**Як підсумок**, *user experience* залежно від контексту може бути:

- [найчастіше] *взаємодія користувача* (з продуктом, сервісом або інтерфейсом)
- *інтерфейс* (з яким взаємодіє користувач)
- *оптимізація взаємодії користувача* (як діяльність або комплекс заходів)
- *досвід/враження/відчуття* (користувача від взаємодії)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту і вітаю вас з якісним першим дописом!

Comment: Дуже якісна відповідь. Я завжди казав - англійське слово або словосполучення зазвичай не має одного перекладу на українську, а має як мінімум декілька залежно від контексту

Answer (score 9):

суб'єктивні відчуття - то є [*враження*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vrazhennja), тобто user experience  можна перекласти як *враження від користування*

хоча переклад звісно не достатньо точний і може бути дослівно переплутаний з User Impression

Comment: Гадаю самі англомовні не зрозуміють різниці між *user experience* і *user impression*

Answer (score 8):

При перекладі *user experience* часто виникає плутанина із *usability*. У цій відповіді я хотів би розібратись у чому різниця, бо це важливо для правильного перекладу.

Отже, розповсюджені помилки

1. Якщо щось легко використовувати, то воно має хороший *user experience*
2. Щось прекрасне, то воно магічним чином стає легким або зручним у використанні.

> *Usability* - про взаємодію на основі задач. Можливість робити щось
>   інтуїтивно і легко. *User experience* - про почуття від взаємодії.
>   Емоційний зв'язок із задачею.

```
------------------------------------------------------
 Usability               | UX
                         |
 Зробити задачу легкою   | Зробити задачу значимою
 та інтуїтивною          | і важливою
                         |
 Мінімізувати кроки і    | Створити емоційний зв'язок
 позбутись перепон       |
                         |
 Що користувач робить /  | Що користувач відчуває
 Як він це робить        |
```

*Usability* - це лише один з багатьох прошарків, що впливають на *User eperience*.

Чудовий *user experience* потребує набагато більше зусиль ніж якісна *usability*.

*Частковий переклад [цього.](http://www.slideshare.net/domain7/ux-vs-usability)*

---

У світлі цього мені подобається [варіант від Chizh](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/417/9)

Comment: Додам, що основною метою UX проектувальника є досягнення [*потоку*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)). Тобто користувача має "засмоктувати", час перестає відчуватися. На думку спадає щось на кшталт *користувацька залу́ка* (словотвір, щоб відрізняти від *залучення* — *involvement*)

Comment: Ніколи не спадало на думку, що UX може йтися про короткочасне враження від взаємодії з програмою. Чи може бути так, що в цьому терміні поєднуються обидва значення англ. слова _experience_, згадані в запитанні? Сама ж вживаю «користувацький досвід».

Comment: @ata_zh досвід якось ближче до знань, тут більше про враження, емоції.

Comment: @yola, так, я розумію. Невже значення слова «досвід» українською заважає говорити про емоційний досвід? (Мені збоку доводять, що заважає, але я просто не можу збагнути. Адже говорять про гіркий чи приємний досвід, чи ще якось так).

Comment: @ata_zh гм.., мабуть, ви праві.

Answer (score 7):

Переклад не має бути дослівним, важливо перекрити суть та більшість випадків використання. В IT сфері важливим є теж кількість місця, яке займає переклад, чим краще воно відповідає ориґінальному місцю під це повідомлення - тим менше проблем буде при локалізації.

Один з варіантів, що можу запропонувати - це **зручність використання** чи **зручність користування**, і опустити забарвлення від User взагалі.

Відповідно:

- *Good User Experience* - це *зручний в користуванні*, чи *висока зручність користування*.
- *Bad User Experience* - це *незручний в користуванні*, чи *низька зручність користування*.

Comment: Пробачте, але відповідь не містить відповіді: **«зручність»** — це те саме слово, що виділено жирним у першому абзаці запитання. Окрім того, відповіді виду «я раджу» бажано підтверджувати посиланнями на те, як запропонована версія використовується кимось іще.

Comment: -1, ви переклали **usability**

Comment: @Yola, я задавав собі це питання (чи не є `зручність використання` еквівалентом `usability`), але не прийшов до таких однозначних висновків. Приклади, над якими я роздумував - це були лідери online сфери України, rozetka та privat24, і аспект який я розглядав - це був досвід спілкування з їх службою підтримки (як елемент user experience), і в цих випадках все одно "зручність користування" покривала такі елементи.

Comment: Ці поняття дійсно перетинаються. І нам треба мати переклади для обох. Можливо тоді варто розглядати переклад одразу двох термінів?